# .NET API for music programming?

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, midi, jfugue

In short words I am looking for a .NET translation of [JFugue](http://jfugue.org/).

**Update**
I realize that there is no real .NET alternative for JFugue, the posts bellow are always great as a guideline for one who wants to develop it by his own.
Thanks for all of you.

Note: I want to emphsize that my search is on the transcription part, not the playing part, in other words, I am looking for a .NET engine that has MIDI-mapping classes etc.

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) seems to be the hottest alternative so far.

Comment: I don't know of a .NET implementation of JFugue (as the author of JFugue, I have pretty good insight into this). Let me know if you'd like my advice in creating something new!

Comment: @David As soon as I saw the StackOverflow ad for JFugue, I started looking for NFugue :-)

Comment: @Ben, make sure to pop in once you got sn' news...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [NAudio](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=naudio) by [Mark Heath](https://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/search/label/NAudio), a great .NET music library I would say it should be contained in the BCL.

[image: logo]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/logo?cct=1259803335))</sub>
[midi-dot-net](https://code.google.com/archive/p/midi-dot-net)
Another great C# project by Tom Lokovic.

Answer (score 1):

Carl Franklin the host of dotnet rocks has done some work with this, if you look at his code samples it may help: http://www.franklins.net/dotnet.aspx.

He also did a [screen cast on Midi routers](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=110).

Hope this helps

Comment: It's far beyond JFuge, but thanks for posting. If you find additional stull I will appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help or not: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/SheetMusicRecorder09242005060541AM/SheetMusicRecorder.aspx

its a musical keyboard, but you should be able to reverse engineer the source code and adapt it to suit what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Midi Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx) before as a starting point, perhaps you find it useful.

BTW, JFugue is not only a library, but also a syntax. I'm working on porting it to Ruby, and it'd be nice if someone (you, maybe?) port it to .NET =)

Comment: Exactly, I am talking about the syntax! that's why I mentioned "like Fugue"

Answer (score 1):

[DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) has MIDI based music programming capabilities. There is no sound generation there, only composing API allowing to create MIDI files. A quick example:

```cs
Pattern pattern = new PatternBuilder()

    // Insert a pause of 5 seconds
    .StepForward(new MetricTimeSpan(0, 0, 5))

    // Insert an eighth C# note of the 4th octave
    .Note(Octave.Get(4).CSharp, MusicalTimeSpan.Eighth)

    // Set default note length to triplet eighth and default octave to 5
    .SetNoteLength(MusicalTimeSpan.Eighth.Triplet())
    .SetOctave(5)

    // Now we can add triplet eighth notes of the 5th octave in a simple way
    .Note(NoteName.A)
    .Note(NoteName.B)
    .Note(NoteName.GSharp)

    // Get pattern
    .Build();

// Now we can export pattern to MIDI file

MidiFile midiFile = pattern.ToFile(TempoMap.Default);
midiFile.Write("My Great Song.mid");
```

As you can see it is not a replacement of JFugue at now since there is no special syntax here, just .NET API.

Comment: I'm not into this anymore currently, but sounds great!

Answer (score 0):

Well, not just like JFugue but I've used the BASS library for .Net. You can find the library at [the un4seen web](http://www.un4seen.com/)

It has audio control and midi thru plugins. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am focusing in the music transcription part, which BASS doesn't provide at all.